# выборка с учётом распределения признака в другой таблице

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть df1 в формате

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})
```

В df1 признак group распределяется следующим образом:
`df1.group.value_counts(normalize=True,dropna = False)`
a - 0.50000
b - 0.33333
c - 0.16667

Есть df2 в аналогичном формате, но с другим распределением признака group.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c']})
```

В df2 признак group распределяется следующим образом:
`df2.group.value_counts(normalize=True,dropna = False)`
c - 0.45455
b - 0.27273
a - 0.27273

Задача: сделать максимально большую подвыборку из df2, чтобы в этой подвыборке распределение признака group было бы такое же, как в df1. Если невозможно максимально большую, то хотя бы подвыборку любого размера.

Comment: Пробовала решать так, но не работает, выдаёт одну строку:  1) t = pd.concat([df1['group'].value_counts(normalize=True,dropna = False),
                df1['group'].value_counts(dropna = False)], 
                axis=1,
                keys=('perc','count')).reset_index()
t.columns = ['group','perc','count_']
2) df2 = pd.merge(df2,t, on='group', how='left') 3) df2_sample = df2.sample(weights = control_feature.perc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

Правда немного громоздко вышло.

Смотрим на распределение:

```
rate = df1['group'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)
```

найдем максимальное значение

```
val = rate.max()
```

Создадим из распределения фрейм, а затем найдем для какой переменной это значение является максимальным, а на случай, если максимальное значение принадлежит нескольким переменным, то возьмем первое.

```
df_max = pd.DataFrame(rate)
max_gr = df_max[df_max.group == val].index.values[0]
```

Далее найдем количество этой переменной во втором фрейме, который будем семплировать по распределению первого фрейма.

```
count_of_max = df2[df2.group == max_gr]['group'].count()
```

и теперь коэффициент

```
koef = count_of_max/rate[max_gr]
```

и наконец сама выборка с аналогичным распределением.

```
sample_df = df2.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.sample(int(koef * rate[x.name]))).reset_index(drop=True)

>>> sample_df
   id group
0  12     a
1  11     a
2  13     a
3  19     b
4  14     b
5  20     c
```

по идее все решение в последней строчке, но самое интересное, это найти этот коэффициент, чтобы получить выборку с распределением максимального размера.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо! Логика понятна, но не получается(  Что не так, можете подсказать?
rate = df1['group'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)
val = rate.max()
max_gr = rate[pd.DataFrame(rate).group == val].index.values[0] --здесь заменила таблицы, т.к. в скрипте выше несуществующая таблица df_max
count_of_max = df2[df2.group == max_gr]['group'].count()
koef = count_of_max/rate[max_gr]
sample_df = df2.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.sample(round(koef * rate[x.name]))).reset_index(drop=True) --получается TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: исправил с созданием df. у вас все верно в комментарии, правда в max_gr вы берете rate[df_max], а нужно df_max[df_max]

Comment: Сейчас сделала точно по вашему скрипту, при создании sample_df всё равно возникает ошибка "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". Не подскажете, в чём может быть причина?

Comment: на этих данных или на других? давайте посмотрим

Comment: а вообще давайте поменяем *round* на *int*, и посмотрим, по идее должно сработать)

Comment: супер, с int работает! спасибо большое!)